# Log in with authorization manager: is there a difference to logging in in with HTTP-Requests in terms of load and stress?

Tags: jmeter, basic-authentication, stress-testing

Currently Im using JMeter to do a stresstest for a website. This website requires a login with username and password. So the first approach I used to login into the site was with HTTP-Requests and parameters, that worked. Now I saw in the documentation that there is an authorization manager to handle the login and I used this approach, it worked too, even for multiple users.

My question is, **is there an important difference between those two approaches in terms of load or stress?**

The reason for asking this is when I use the 
authorization manager to login, there are no HTTP-Post-Requests shown in the View Results that show the login via HTTP-Request. But this would be the case if a normal user would login into the site. So are they just not shown in the Results or should I use HTTP-Requests to login when I want to come as close as possible to a real world simulation?

Thank you for your answers and time!

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) is needed to bypass **external** authentication types like:

- [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme)
- [NTLM Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
- [Kerberos](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780469(v=ws.10).aspx)

Normally you should go for HTTP Authorization Manager when your application is configured to use a 3rd-party service for authorizing users in addition to (or instead of) "normal" username/password authentication like when you get [http response status code 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

---

Now let's review your "worked" outcome. JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful no matter whether login succeeded or not so my expectation is that in one of scenarios (if not in both) your test silently fails. Inspect response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see the actual responses HTML and ensure that you are **really** logged in as it might be the case that you continuously hitting login page. I would recommend adding a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to add an extra check whether the virtual user has landed to home page, dashboard, whatever so the assertion will test if elements which are specific for logged in user only (welcome text, logout link, etc.) are present or not. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about how to add pass/fail criteria to your JMeter test scripts.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help and the explanation you gave to me. To comment on your point with the silent fails. I checked that for both scenarios and the login works. How can I be sure of that? I did what you said and was viewing the response and the fields and content that is hidden from a user without login is there and can be viewed. To go a step  further I removed the password in both cases and hit the page again, this time, the fields didnt show up, both cases work as expected. So my question remains, are there any differences in terms of perfomance?

Comment: Your load test needs to mimic real life application usage as close as possible, if real users are entering credentials in a modal popup - you should go for HTTP Authorization Manager, if they type credentials into HTML inputs - you should be using HTTP Request parameters

Comment: Thanks for claryfying that. Since I did not find this information by google and research, do you have any source or documentation for what you just explained to me?